# How can I make a type that can be either a String or an Integer?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to make a type that can represent either an operator ("+", "-", "*", ...) or operand (1, 2, 3, 4 ...) for a postfix expression calculator.

I tried writing:

```
data PostfixToken = String | Integer
```

But then say I have a dummy function like this:

```
foo :: Bool -> PostfixToken
foo x = 3 :: Integer
```

I get:

```
Couldn't match type ‘Integer’ with ‘PostfixToken’
```

Why can't it match Integer with PostfixToken, though I explicitly defined the type as such? What would be the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sum types must be *tagged* unions. In Haskell, the tags are simultaneously *data constructors*.

```
data PostfixToken = Operator String | Operand Integer

foo :: Bool -> PostfixToken
foo x = Operand 3
```